# Legal and illegal uses of `::`

Tags: syntax, verilog, system-verilog

I looked into a code like this. For Example:

```
typedef C;
C::T x; //illegal;

typedef C::T c_t; //legal
c_t y;

class C;
   typedef int T;
endclass
```

Why is the first use `::` of illegal and the second legal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SystemVerilog requires that a type identifier must be known to be a type before you can reference that type. This is explained at the beginning of Section 6.18 of the 1800-2017 LRM where this example comes from.

The problem with your declaration of `x` is that `C::T` is not a known type at that point.

When you put a `typedef` in front of `C::T` the parser knows that it must be a type, there is no other valid choice.

Answer (score 0):

The double colon is used the scope resolution operator. It is used for accessing classes within a package and static data within a class.

You can find good usage examples in the page 14 of [this reference manual](https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~hadi/teaching/cs3220/doc/modelsim/ModelSim_Reference_Manual_v10.1c.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

This is the class scope resolution operator. It is used to specify an identifier defined within the scope of a class. Because classes and other scopes can have the same identifiers, the class scope resolution operator uniquely identifies a member, a parameter or local parameter of a particular class.

More info can be found in [IEEE 1800-2017](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~mathys/ecen2350/IntelSoftware/pdf/IEEE_Std1800-2017_8299595.pdf), ch. 8.23 Class scope resolution operator.